# Partitioning options

Tags: partitioning

So far I've always been using the simplest partitioning option possibile for my Ubuntu installations:

- **/** (ext4) 50 GB
- **swap** 2GB (the size of the RAM installed)
- **ntfs** (Data) -> the remaining GBs, with the idea, which never occurred, that maybe someday I'll need Windows again, so I've kept my data in a NTFS partition to eventually access it also from Windows. 
  Later on, I found out that with Ext2Fsd you can access your data partition from Windows also if it is formatted as ext4.

Now after reading [this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=282018) and others on the internet, I am about to make these changes:

1) Ubuntu 12.04 LTS notebook (100 GB HDD, no dual boot):

```
/     -> 15 GB
/home -> 20 GB (needed for some large programs such as CAELinux, Matlab, etc.)
/data (ext4) -> all the remaining GBs
swap  -> 2 GB
```

2) Ubuntu 12.10 netbook (320 GB HDD, Windows dual boot, 3 GB RAM)

```
/     -> 20 GB
/home -> 30 GB
/data -> all the remaining GBs. Meant to be accessible also from Windows.
swap  -> 2GB
ntfs  -> 20 GB (Windows)
```

1. In this way I'll be able to encrypt only the files in /home and not the ones in /data, right?
2. Would the /data partition be accessible to someone who doesn't know my Ubuntu login password?
3. In future, could I install a new distro/release simply by formatting the "/" partition, without making any change and/or loosing any data in my /home and /data partitions, keeping all my files there? (of course I'll back up all the files, but just for info)
4. What appens to my current encrypted /home folders? Will I be able to format them correctly without any space loss (i.e., an hidden backup/space allocation for my previously encrypted /home folders)?
5. Even if I am seldomly going to use Windows, should the ntfs partition be the first one in my partitioning tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this way I'll be able to encrypt only the files in /home and not the ones in /data, right?

Yes.

> Would the /data partition be accessible to someone who doesn't know my Ubuntu login password?

Yes. It is unencrypted so someone that has access could reboot with a live cd, mount the disc and extract the contents.

> In future, could I install a new distro/release simply by formatting the "/" partition, without making any change and/or loosing any data in my /home and /data partitions, keeping all my files there? (of course I'll back up all the files, but just for info)

Yes. If you do not format home at that time and just mount it as home and use the same username(!) for the new system.

> What happens to my current encrypted /home folders? Will I be able to format them correctly without any space loss (i.e., an hidden backup/space allocation for my previously encrypted /home folders)?

Ehm, you are not formatting /home... You said that in the other question. If you format it the data is gone... encrypted or not encrypted, hidden or not hidden. 
You mount /home during a format/re-install.

> Even if I am seldomly going to use Windows, should the ntfs partition be the first one in my partitioning tree?

No, unless it contains the OS.

Comment: Note that as of this writing there is a bug in the Ubiquity installer that causes it to hang when one tries to do your #3.